# Inserting multiple data into multiple table simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-query-store

I have four tables and I need to add details to these tables.
The tables listed are below:

facility table:

```
id    code  name
fac1  ab1   abanglr
```

Row table:

```
rowid   facilityid   rowName    resourceid
row1     fac1         a          rec1
```

Resource table:

```
Resouceid    facilityid    userid    length width
rec1           fac1         user1      10     10
```

User Table:

```
 userid name
 user1   xyz
```

1. select userid from user table
2. select facility id from facility table
3. add new row which adds details in both row and resource table.
4. add resourceid in row table and row id in resorce table

when I mean adding new row meaning it has row name, row length, row width and many more detail. How do I do that? Please guide me as I am new to sql

adding constraint of row table if this could be used as any help

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_Row] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RowID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Row]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Row_Resource] FOREIGN KEY([ResourceID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Resource] ([ResourceID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Row] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Row_Resource]
GO
```

Comment: Your schema is not normalized, and the row and resource tables duplicate each other.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am sorry for the interruption. could you show or say why schema is not normalized? I've seen tables, but tables have foreign keys. I really would like to know what it is wrong here.

Comment: The relationships between resources and facilities is spread out across two tables.